# Can't start atom from terminal after restart

Tags: macos, atom-editor

While using my macOs I would love to start the Atom from the terminal and I did the install shell commands from Atom, the problem is that every time I restart the machine I have to redo that to make it working again.
Do anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you not able to run Atom after restarting your system or are you forced to reinstall your Atom packages? What do you mean by "install shell commands from Atom"?

Comment: Shell commands is an option in atom that allows you to start the atom from the terminal. This actually works until I restart.